# Is a certain coding trustworthy?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering.. Can code just not behave as you wish? 
I am making a little project, and in every page I have a button that will take you back to home.. but the problem is, there is a certain (and I think it will be in some other pages too) page that I am working on (I work page by page so I know what I have done and what not) and the float doesn't set the button in the middle..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>April</h2>
        </div>
        <!--ending header-->
        <div class="nav">
            <div id="red"><a href="Januaridata.php">Vakantie gegevens</a></div>
            <div id="indigo"><a href="Maartdata.php">Overwerk gegevens</a></div>
            <div id="green"><a href="Meidata.php">A.D.V gegevens</a></div>
            <div id="deeporange"><a href="Julidata.php">Reiskosten gegevens</a>
            </div>
            <!--ending the nav class-->
            <div id="footer">
                <a href="home.php"><img src="home-button.jpg" alt="Breng me terug"></a>
                <h2>Contact gegevens</h2>
            </div>
            <!--ending footer-->
        </div>
        <!--ending container-->

</body>




img {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 50% 0 0;
}
```

now my question is, how can I set it in the middle AND how come the button doesn't behave like on other pages?

Notice: I commented out the class nav to see how the button would respond and it did center after I took that out. So I guess the problem has to be somehwere in my "a"?

```
.nav a {
width: 250px;
padding: 10px 16px;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
height:20vh;
line-height: 20vh;
text-align: center;
font-size: 150%;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 12px;
```

}

Comment: Waht is in your normalise and style.css? You can use jsfiddle to show working (not working) example.

Comment: can you post your linked css. Especially css for the footer

Comment: What do you mean with linked css? You need all my css coding? (sorry, didn't get the question)

Comment: @Dominus There might be some other css, what overrides your css (especially with such a common selector as "img"). Use browser's "inspect element" to check.

Comment: is there an easier way to give all the coding that has been used in my css then copy paste? I mean, it will be A LOT of css to look at if I were to copy paste it here. I checked it out aswell, and it looks as if something is blocking my button, someone commented that I should use margin: 0 auto and display: block, but when doing so it stays on the left (moves very little to right note: As if something is preventing it from moving?)

Comment: @Dominus Did you remove the float:right ? Floating stuff can get stuck behind edges of other elements.

Comment: I just did yeah, someone said it would be better to use margin: 0 auto and display block, so I changed the code (no floating for the button anymore). I could post a page where both float and display work and center it if you like to? Maybe u'll notice something?

Comment: When you use "inspect element" tool, check styles and locations of the parent elements too. This might be, that your "a" or "div footer" are smaller than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to center image, do not use % margins and floating, as both of these are quite dependent, what other elements are near the element.

You can set image to be block and give this auto margins:

```css
img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>April</h2>
            </div><!--ending header-->
                <div class="nav">
                    <div id="red"><a href="Januaridata.php">Vakantie gegevens</a></div>
                    <div id="indigo"><a href="Maartdata.php">Overwerk gegevens</a></div>
                    <div id="green"><a href="Meidata.php">A.D.V gegevens</a></div>
                    <div id="deeporange"><a href="Julidata.php">Reiskosten gegevens</a>
                </div><!--ending the nav class-->
            <div id="footer">
            <a href="home.php"><img src="home-button.jpg" alt="Breng me terug"></a>
            <h2>Contact gegevens</h2>
            </div><!--ending footer-->
        </div><!--ending container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

A computer is a machine : **it does what you tell it to do**.

Most of the time, the issue is coming from you, and not the computer.

This means that somewhere, you changed something, and it impacted your user interface.

There are plenty of ways to center an element into a container, and floating it isn't the best one.

If you could post some code, such as your CSS, or even **make a fiddle**, we could probably help you with this issue.

Comment: oh oke, im sorry, but I never used with the fiddle stuff :/ so i'll have to look into that one.

Comment: @Dominus Just use "add code snippet" button, when editing your post.